# Pass CheckBox-Objects

Tags: vba, checkbox

How do I have to pass CheckBox-Objects correct to other Subs/Functions?
Had to pass it multiples times. For illustation it worked for 
case 1: MsgBox "1) " & ckBox.Name 
but not in:
case 2: MsgBox "2) " & ckBox.Name

It starts with a Click-Event from the ClickBox in "ControlBox_Click_100".

```
# Modul_1 ---------------------------------------------------
Sub ControlBox_Click_100()
    Call fColOnOff(bRowSearch, "New", "Old", , True)
End Sub


# Modul_2 ---------------------------------------------------
Sub fColOnOff(ByVal bRow As Byte, Optional ByVal sSuchen1 As String, _
                                  Optional ByVal sSuchen2 As String, _
                                  Optional ByVal sSuchen3 As String, _
                                  Optional ByVal bolSuchen2 As Boolean, _
                                  Optional ByVal bolSuchen3 As Boolean) _

Call fActCheckBox

    MsgBox "2) " & ckBox.Name

...

End Sub


# Modul_2 ---------------------------------------------------
Private Sub fActCheckBox()

Dim ckBox As CheckBox
Set ckBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

    MsgBox "1) " & ckBox.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "it worked in case 1 ... but not in case 2" what exactly do you mean. Are you getting an error? Is it simply not doing what you expect?

Comment: `Private Sub fActCheckBox(chk as Control)`

Comment: Did not work. CheckBox is equal to Control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constellations like this you can handle with a global variable. This worked:

```
Public ckBox As CheckBox

Function fActCheckBox()
Set ckBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller) 
    MsgBox "1) " & ckBox.Name
End Function


Sub fSpalteEinAusBlenden(... )
    MsgBox "2) " & ckBox.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Message 2 doesn't work because `ckBox` is not a valid object in that Sub.

Look at how the checkbox is declared and initiated as an object in `fActCheckbox`:

```
Dim ckBox As CheckBox
Set ckBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
```

`fActCheckbox` stands by itself - there's no link back to `fColonOnOff`; `Call` doesn't have the effect you think it has. All it does is execute another procedure.

If you were to turn `fActCheckbox` into a ***Public Function*** then something would be possible. For example

```
Sub Test
   MsgBox "2 " & fActCheckBox
End Sub

Public Function fActCheckBox() As String
  Dim ckName as String
  Dim ckBox As CheckBox
  Set ckBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

  ckName = ckBox.Name
  MsgBox "1) " & ckName
  fActCheckBox = ckName
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was not I am looking for. Would like to pass back the CheckBox-Object. Need more than only the `.Name`. Find the solution by myself.